# Trying to pass facebook like, send, twitter and google plus as inner html in a user control.

Tags: asp.net, facebook, iframe, twitter

```
$('.PageGry')[0].innerHTML = 'Please confirm';
                    document.getElementById('O_C').innerHTML ='<div class="fb-like" data-href="/unprotected/PayPerView.aspx" data-send="true" data-width="380" data-show-faces="false"></div><iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?via=FlexviewVerizon&text=Check out Verizon Movies Online" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;"></iframe><g:plusone></g:plusone>';
```

I am using facebook like and send, twitter, google plus by passing them like innerhtml as above. This is in ascx file,  but I am not able to figure out where I have to add the below code.

```
 (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
        (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
(function() {
            var scrGooglePlus = document.createElement('script');
            scrGooglePlus.type = 'text/javascript';
            scrGooglePlus.async = true;
            scrGooglePlus.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js' (https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js%27);
            var scrWriter = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            scrWriter.parentNode.insertBefore(scrGooglePlus, scrWriter);
        })();
```

Since twitter is just an iframe, it is being displayed. Can someone suggest me where I have to include so that I can get all these ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know about Facebook, but the following will likely apply to G+ as well:

For the Facebook button you just add that code within a script block. It runs on page load.

The problem is that the JS SDK will initialize before you're adding the like button info via innerHTML, so you need to tell the JS. SDK to reparse the DOM. There's a method like FB.xfbml.parse(). Look through my answers for 'dynamic like button'. I'm traveling right now so can't easily do it for you ;)